# Why is tinting of AppCompatCheckbox failing on Lollipop 5.1 API 22?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-checkbox

This AppCompat code work fine on Marshmallow to tint the checkmark tick, text and background in an AppCompatCheckbox, bu on a Lollipop API 22 device although the text and background are tinted, the checkmark itself is not. Why?

```
    public static void applyThemeToCheckBox(AppCompatCheckBox checkbox, @ColorInt int backgroundColor, @ColorInt int textColor) {
        checkbox.setTextColor(textColor);
        checkbox.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        int[] colors = new int[] {
                textColor,
                textColor,
                textColor,
                textColor
        };
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(getStates(), colors);
        checkbox.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
    }

private static int[][] getStates() {
    return new int[][] {
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
    };
}
```

I looked at using DrawCompat (how are we supposed to know these things exist?) and it is working for me in other scenarios, but I cannot see how to access the checkmark drawable on API 22.

Please no solutions involving static themes, the app is styled dynamically based on an API response, the tinting MUST be done programmatically.

Comment: Did You find any solution ?